# python multiple clients chat doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking

When i run main and client's py files not showing error but doesn't show the input to send the message. how to fix?

*main.py result* -- > Waiting... and connected 192.168.1.26 58767

*clients.py result* -- > nothing

this is main.py

```
import threading
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

host="192.168.1.26"
port=1111
threadcount=0
server.bind((host,port))
print("Waiting...")
server.listen(3)


def clients(connection):
    connection.send(str.encode("welcome\n"))
    while True:
        data=connection.recv(2048)
        reply="server says" + data.decode("utf-8")
        if not data:
            break
        connection.sendall(str.encode(reply))
    connection.close()

while True:
    client,adress=server.accept()
    print("connected"+ str(adress[0]) + " " + str(adress[1]))
    threading.Thread(target=clients,args=(client,))
    threadcount+=1
server.close()
```

this is clients.py

```
import socket

client_socket=socket.socket()
host="192.168.1.26"
port=1111
client_socket.connect((host,port))

response=client_socket.recv(1024)
print("hello")

while True:
    input=input("say")
    client_socket.send(str.encode(input))
    Response=client_socket.recv(1024)
    print(Response.decode("utf-8"))

client_socket.close()
```

Comment: Not the underlying issue, but in your `client.py` code you should absolutely not use `input` as the variable to store the result of `input` the function. Use a different variable name, such as `data`.

Comment: @h0r53 not fix :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your thread is never actually starting. One solution is to define a class that implements your thread logic in a `run` routine. The class should inherit `threading.Thread`. Then you can simply initialize the class as an object and call its `start` routine.  Try the following variant of your original server code.

```
import threading
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

host="192.168.1.26"
port=1111
threadcount=0
server.bind((host,port))
print("Waiting...")
server.listen(3)

class ServerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadsocket):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadsocket = threadsocket

    def run(self):
        self.threadsocket.send(str.encode("welcome\n"))
        while True:
            data=self.threadsocket.recv(2048)
            reply="server says" + data.decode("utf-8")
            print(reply)
            if not data:
                break
            self.threadsocket.sendall(str.encode(reply))
        self.threadsocket.close()

while True:
    client,adress=server.accept()
    print("connected"+ str(adress[0]) + " " + str(adress[1]))
    thread = ServerThread(client)
    thread.start()
    threadcount+=1

server.close()
```

As far as the client, as I mentioned in a comment you should not use `input` as a variable name to store the result of the `input` function. Change it to something like `data` instead.

Comment: server can't send message why?

Comment: Probably a blocked send/read on the client side. Make sure each `send` ends with a `\n` and see if that helps. On my machine the original client works with the new server I provided.